# gazebo database error

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

I'm using ros indigo, ubuntu 14.04 & trying to launch gazebo but it is not working. I have the gazebo_models downloaded (https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models) but i am still getting the following errors when i try to launch gazebo:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.6
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.6
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.206.134
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.206.134
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:228] No <database> tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:287] Unable to download model manifests
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:407] Unable to download model[model://sun]
Error [SystemPaths.cc:367] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [parser.cc:523] Unable to find uri[model://sun]
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:228] No <database> tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:287] Unable to download model manifests
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:407] Unable to download model[model://ground_plane]
Error [SystemPaths.cc:367] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [parser.cc:523] Unable to find uri[model://ground_plane]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:228] No <database> tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:287] Unable to download model manifests
VMware: vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument.
```

Is there any solution?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is any reason for which you are using such an old version of Gazebo? As it is not a version of Gazebo supported anymore, you risk to encounter many problematic behaviors.

Anyhow, you can disable the downloading of the Gazebo Model Database by setting the `GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI` env variable to an empty string, i.e. launch Gazebo as:

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=""
gazebo
```

see https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components .